# How can I query all, orderby, and paginate?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

[image]

I don't know what is wrong with my query, but the count is clearly wrong, it kept showing as `1912` when my total records are `12363`

---

## I tried

to change this line under my default case

```
$q = Visitor::where('created_at', '<', now());
```

to

```
$q = Visitor::all(); but I got error;
```

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.

---

```
switch ($interval) {
    case 'day':
    $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->today());
    break;
    case 'week':
    $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subWeek());
    break;
    case 'month':
    $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subMonth());
    break;
    case 'year':
    $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subYear());
    break;
    case 'last':
    $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', $last);
    break;
    default:
    $q = Visitor::where('created_at', '<', now());
    break;
}


$visitors = $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

---

http://app.test/visitor?interval=year

I got `1912` - correct

---

http://app.test/visitor

I got `1912` - not correct ❌, It should query **all** since the interval is not specified.

If I do :

```
dd(count(Visitor::all()));
```

I got `12363` so that should be the right value.

## Please let me know if you spot what I missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$q = Visitor::all();` returns a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.

Calling `$visitors = $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);` will call `->orderBy(...)` on an Eloquent Collection of which that method doesn't exist in that class.

##### Solution

Instead of:

```php
$q = Visitor::where('created_at', '<', now()); ❌
```

Use this:

```php
$q = Visitor::query(); ✅
```

Comment: Let me try... thanks.

Comment: still get the same result as my yearly..

Comment: It's not working, confirmed, sorry.

Comment: @code-8 I believe that has more to do with your dataset than the query in question. Did you perform a count on it?

Comment: I did, see my `dd(count(Visitor::all()));` show correct count `12363` and I showed that on my left navigation menu in the image;

Comment: You're right!!! I filter out code below; your answer is perfect;

Comment: I see the right count now;

Comment: @code-8 I'm glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `->whereDate('created_at', now())`, with `->whereTime('created_at', '00:00:00')` if you need

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).